# Why can't I vote to delete my own question?

Tags: bug, vote-to-delete, self-delete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Users should be able to participate in deleting their own closed questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110564/users-should-be-able-to-participate-in-deleting-their-own-closed-questions)

I know this is somewhat covered in this [FAQ entry](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean), but why can't I delete my own question?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152386/handling-schema-objects-named-as-sql-keywords

It tells me

> Sorry, this question has answers and cannot be deleted; flag it for moderator attention instead.

I find this rather interesting since I have 20k+ and thus I can vote to delete *any* closed question - but my own.

I am not asking for it to delete my question immediately, but why can't I *vote* to delete my own questions?

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me - perhaps this would be better under a `bug` tag?

Comment: Hmm, maybe it has something to do with having an upvoted answer on the question?  Or maybe because it was closed recently by a moderator?

Comment: @Jeff I am able to vote to delete questions that have upvoted answers and were closed by moderators - as long as they aren't mine.

Comment: @Jeff Mercado 20k users can vote to delete a closed question, even if it new.