# 20k+ owners should be able to vote to delete their own answered questions that they can't ordinarily delete

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-delete

As a 20k rep user, I can vote to delete questions, but I can't vote to delete my own questions.

For example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424480/do-you-trust-code-that-works-the-first-time should be deleted, it doesn't belong on Stack Overflow.

I understand and am fine with not being able to one-click delete it since it has upvoted answers, but I should be able to cast a delete vote for it.

In other words, the rules that prevent one-click deletion by the owner should not supersede the vote-to-delete rules one has for normal posts.

Comment: Related: [Users should be able to participate in deleting their own closed questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110564)

Comment: 2 more votes to go...

Comment: Out of curiosity I wanted to know how isolated this is. I wrote this data.se query [Closed Questions asked by user with the Trusted Privledge](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/61295)

Answer (score 3):

I agree with you totally. Not that I am a 20k+ rep owner. I think that if someone knows that he had asked the wrong question, he should be allowed to delete it. But it really has to be earned or it could be a problem for the community.