# Why am I getting "you may delete this post in 2 days" when trying to delete my question

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-delete, error-message

I've just tried to delete [my previous question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259801/im-not-allowed-to-close-vote-deleted-question-why-can-i-vote-to-reopen-a-delet). Instead of being deleted, this naughty question throws this error:

> [image]

Why is that?

- today I deleted only one post of mine
- today I voted to delete two posts and having three daily votes left
- the two-days limit typically applies only when deleting *not* my posts

[I thought this was fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117933/allow-the-author-to-delete-their-own-question-after-closure-if-other-rules-perm)...

Comment: This appears to be the first disadvantage of the 10k tools -  *more. bugs.*

Comment: Because you have 10k, therefore you 'vote to delete' instead of just deleting.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have no idea how convoluted the deletion voting code is... seems I missed an edge case with 10K rep users when [originally removing the self-delete restriction of closed questions.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/187900/3)

A test has been written (for what that's worth) and a fix will be push out shortly.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what an edge case it was?

Comment: Oh, it was purely not putting an owner check on the `if` statement for 10K users.  Not that much of an edge case, I guess, where a more experienced user gets their question closed and then wants to delete.